# How safe is to secure sensitive content by URL with MD5 hash and no other authorization?

Tags: security, url, hash, web-crawler, md5

Suppose we have website that use MD5 hash in URL like this:

```
http://somewebsite.com/XXX/
```

where `XXX` is MD5 hash.

Content of this website may have sensitive information like transaction details with personal data.

There is no other authorization to this website, so if you have URL you can access it.

**How safe is it?** I mean, if no one will share URL with anyone, then can I assume no one will access it?

How much time could it take web crawler, to crawl through all combinations of such url?

I ask because I am using some web shop, that store transaction details with personal data in such manner, I am saying them that it's not secure and someone can view their clients sensitive data, but they are not convinced. To build web crawler it's simple to me, I know how to do this, but I don't know how much time it will crawl through all combinations, maybe at shop they are right? This is not about my website, I am end user of that shop, and I need to convince them they are wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of "[security by obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity)", and it should be considered unsafe.

Just for the fun of it, lets think about it a bit more.

You say it's a hash. A hash of what? Is it possible that a hacker guesses or knows what you are hashing, and starts guessing from there? BTW, how will you ensure that hashes are unique?

Sure, an MD5 hash is 128 bits, but if the thing you're hashing doesn't have 128 bits of information, it doesn't really help. Maybe the thing you're hashing is a sequence number? In that case, guessing the next hash could be trivially easy.

Even then, MD5 is considered broken now, and not fit for security usage. For more information, take a look at the [Wikipedia article on MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5).

More importantly, you create these URLs, but you need to send them somehow to the user. How will you do that? Not in a clear text e-mail I hope. Maybe you publish them on a properly secured website, where they can click on the link after properly logging on. Oh, wait... no probably not.

If you want to keep something safely confidential, secure it properly. Require a logon. And use SSL/TLS, i.e. HTTPS instead of HTTP.